# Close silverlight applications and redirect to parent applications

Tags: c#, silverlight, redirect

My company is developing a Silverlight application which we then give to our clients who integrate it with their product. You can log into the application by going through a form or using a URI where you pass some needed data. If you provide false data (i.e. you can not be authenticated) you get a message and the applications closes. Then the user just has a blank (white) screen in front of him. We don't want that to be the case any more. Instead we would like to redirect to the calling page (where the user clicked the link to start the app).

So if for example user A has his application open on `http://hisdomain.com/work` and clicks on a link that redirects him to our Silverlight app where the authentication fails we would like to show him a message (this is happening at the momment) and then redirect him back to `http://hisdomain.com/work`.

Any ideas how to do this?

I am still in R&D about this so I have not much of an idea about it. The only thing that came to my mind was to pass in the calling URL along with the rest of the data.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

If you can pass the starting URL into the Silverlight app with the startup params, you can redirect back with this:

```
System.Windows.HtmlPage.Window.Navigate(new Uri("YourStartupUrl.aspx", UriKind.Relative));
```

Comment: That's what I head in mind too... Just append something like `&StartingURL=foo.bar` and then pick it up as i parse the query string. Thanks for that

Comment: I don't have time to try it right now but I was thinking it might be possible to pick the address up from the ASPX that hosts the silverlight app and pass it into the SL InitParams in the ASPX codebehind (or put it in the web.config). That way it's not on the URL and you have less to configure.

Comment: @IvanCrojachKaračić Crojach Karačić Are you using the System.Windows.HtmlPage.Window.Navigate method in the Silverlight client code?  That would fail because Silverlight is not an System.Windows.HtmlPage  .Are there any other alternatives?